# R.animator with objectAnimators aren't working with Fragment add/remove animations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I don't know why this is always so hard to get working. I'm using the AppCompat Library and `android.app.Fragment`. I try to add animations to slide new fragments in left/right (like iOS does), but when the fragments are added they are adding / removing instantly, without any animation.

What am I doing wrong?

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_right, R.animator.slide_out_to_the_left)
    .add(R.id.navrootlayout, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

res/animator/slide_in_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_cubic"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

res/animator/slide_out_to_the_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_cubic"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

I even set the duration of the animation to 3000 (i.e. 3 seconds) so that I could DEFINITELY see if it was being used at all, but it's not. The fragment is added without any animation at all. I captured a screen video of it happening, and the new fragment appears (and eventually disappears) instantly.

Comment: What property is "xFraction"?

Comment: Yeeeeaaaah, I just spent the last hour figuring that out. Apparently, the example code I got this from assumed that I would be adding custom properties to my Layout classes, but they didn't mention that.

Comment: I think the reason for it is with Animators there is no relative translation mechanism so you can't slide in.  Creating an "xFraction" animation (percentage of "X" I assume) let's you do the slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had grabbed the animation xml files from an example somewhere, and that example didn't happen to mention that I needed to implement the `xFraction` property myself. I wrongly assumed that this was a built-in behavior that would understand xFraction and x were related, similar to the way that the old style `res/anim` style animations would allow you to use percentage values as the animation start/end values.

But, nope. In order to do this, you have to create a subclass of your layout and add the `xFraction` property yourself. This is how I did it.

```
package com.mydomain.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class SlideableLayout extends RelativeLayout {


    public SlideableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlideableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlideableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public float getXFraction() {
        final int width = getWidth();
        if (width != 0) {
            return getX() / getWidth();
        } else {
            return getX();
        }
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        if (width > 0) {
            setX(xFraction * width);
        } else {
            setX(-10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for each of my Fragments that I want to animate on and off the screen, I use my `SlideableLayout` as the root layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mydomain.myapp.SlideableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    >

</com.mydomain.myapp.SlideableLayout>
```